# TikZ inserting text

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw the picture attached using TikZ. Red lines are not needed. I only need to draw the squared root of s. I use the code below, however, don't know how to insert the "s" in it. In addition, how can I change the linewidth of the first line ? it should be wider than the other lines.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,4) -- (1,1) -- (2,6) -- (6,6);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Attached

[image: picture]

Comment: I would recommend you check out the options on page 7 and 16 of the "Minimal Introduction to TikZ" available from [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf)

Comment: Is there a special reason, to "draw" this root? Why do you not use:                   `\node[scale=5.3] {$\sqrt{s}$};`

Comment: yes I need this or something similar to this one.

Comment: I check the document, Minimal int. to TikZ, but still having problems to do it:(

Comment: Aha, the way setting text on drawed things is using "nodes". 
For example: `\draw (0,4) -- (1,1) node[green, right, xshift=2mm]{some text} -- (2,6) -- (6,6);`

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.25]
\draw[red]
  (0,0) grid (5,6);
\draw[line width=8pt]
  (0,4) -- (1,0);
\draw[thick]
  (1.08,0.1) -- (1.5,6) -- (5,6);
\node[scale=22,font=\sffamily] at (3,2)
  {s};    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you are after upright square root symbol and trying to make it with `tikz`. If so, the following may be useful.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\upsqrt}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(a.base)}]
  \node[inner sep=2pt] (a) {\hspace*{0.5ex}$#1$};
  \draw[line cap=round] ([yshift=0.5ex]a.west) -- +(-1pt,-0.7pt);
  \draw[thick] ([yshift=0.5ex]a.west) -- ([xshift=0.7ex]a.south west);
  \draw[line cap=round] ([xshift=0.7ex]a.south west) -- ([xshift=0.7ex]a.north west) -- (a.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
This is up right square root $\upsqrt{S}$ and this too $\upsqrt{x}$ and this is normal $\sqrt{x}$ $\sqrt{S}$
\end{document}
```

[image]